# Where to find a computation example of the monero traceable ring signature mechanism in a small finite field?

Tags: monerod, monero-research-lab

In the following coindesk article, [The math behind bitcoin](http://www.coindesk.com/math-behind-bitcoin), you can find a beautiful example of the ECDSA keypair generation, signature and signature verification algorithms in use in bitcoin. They illustrate the address generation in a finite field of order n=67 and the signing/verification in n=79, which keeps the computations manageable; even with just a calculator.

I suspect that a basic monero/cryptonote calculation example would be quite a bit longer. Still, even such longer article would be interesting to a lot of people, in order to gain a better understanding of what monero/cryptonote actually do.

Does such article exist already? (I could not find one ...)

If there is no such elaborated exercise available, I would certainly be interested in composing (and even publishing) one; if I could find help for corrections and verifications. Do you know of starting point drafts/links/documents, suitable for the composition of such numerical example?

Note: Formulas and formal proofs are interesting in their own right, but I guess that they are not as suitable as starting points like a good numerical example.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried https://lab.getmonero.org/ and the cryptonote whitepaper(s) here? https://getmonero.org/research-lab/ They have some very thorough documents on the technology at a more academic level.

Comment: I have just looked through the papers: whitepaper, annotated whitepaper, whitepaper review, MRL-0003, MRL-0004, MRL-0005. There is indeed one calculation program that could possibly illustrate things in https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf, "Appendix B: Ring CT Demo Code". However, it does not allow you to compute manually any example results, just by using a calculator. I actually would like to repeat the computation procedure manually, not in a field with order 2^255-19, but in a field with order 2^6-19 or 2^7-19, in a similar simplification/illustration as in the bitcoin article.